# Firebase Cloud functions: manipulate image before sending to the user

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to write a cloud firebase function capable of triggering when a user requests a specific image and before sending it to him modify it by applying a graphic filter. I don't want that filter is applied on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to write a cloud function for that and call that instead of accessing the bucket directly. There is no way to interfere with the request directly to a bucket.

I have found a basic tutorial to send an image from a cloud function [here](https://jsmobiledev.com/article/cloud-function-image-base64), but I don't know if that completely fits your needs, so you might have to look for more elaborate tutorials.

To modify the image there are some JS libraries out there, I suggest you look into one of them. One of them is already included into cloud functions [as it seems](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation)

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer is just what I was looking for. But I was wondering if I could use some external javascript libraries to modify the image. Or at most I can only use pure javascript libraries?

Comment: What do you mean with "external" @user12002919 ? It should be a library that you import with npm. It could be an  external tool, hosted somewhere else on the web, but I would advise STRONGLY against that!

Comment: As MauriceNino mentionned [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) is installed by default on all Cloud Functions instances. It is a library with a lot of available transformation possibilities. If you need to use another library, install it via npm (As explained by Maurice)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest you have a trigger that fires when the raw/original image is first *saved*, and use a Cloud Function to make your modifications and then store *that* result for the user to call directly.  Cold starts are always a possible issue with Cloud Functions, and even without that you would be adding another layer of latency into the user experience.

Note this works even with "live" isochronous code - when the user uploads the "original", trigger/call the cloud function to generate the filtered version.  This will overlap at least somewhat with the user interactions (especially if they have a few choices to make), possibly making the app feel more responsive.

Comment: thanks, you are right. But for what i need to do, just in my case (not in general), there will be more latency doing what you said. But it's just my case. Thanks man.

Comment: See updated answer - there are often ways to "hide" the latency